Dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 /home drive visible inside windows
I have dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11 installed on separate SSDs. Both have separate EFI Partition. My Ubuntu /home partition is visible inside windows which is a NTFS partition. I don't want it to be visible inside windows. I followed ubuntu default installation process without customising anything.

Your /home should not  be seen by Windows. Ubuntu requires /home to be Linux formatted, default ext4. Did you install a Windows driver to see ext4 partitions? That is not recommended as it can create issues. Often a shared NTFS data partition is suggested if you want to share some data between systems. Post this in question above: lsblk -f and sudo parted -l
